# Why is the variable read from the Scanner method next() or nextDouble() equal to a String or double respectively

Tags: java, string, file

For example,

If I declare a String variable and a double variable

```
String d = "dragon";
double = 1.45;
```

And then I have a text file and on the first line of the file it is...

A dragon is 1.45

So I open the file

```
 {
         try {
             x = new Scanner(new File("Dragon.txt"));

         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             System.out.println("Could not find file");
         }
     }
// And then read in the data, in this case I use hasNext which returns a String.
     public void readFileData()
     {
         while(x.hasNext())
         {

  // Remember, this is the first line of the text file: A dragon is 1.45
         String a1 = x.next();  // al = "A";
         String a2 = x.next();  // a2 = "dragon;

// And I test a2 to see it is equal to dragon, however it is not.

         if(d == a2)
         {
             System.out.println("Wow");
         }
         else
             System.out.println("Naw man");
         String a3 = x.next();
         String a4 = x.next(); 

// Of course I do the same thing for the a4 variable and of course the String variables are replaced with double and nextdouble() method is used.
```

Thank you very much in advance to anyone who can help!

Comment: I do not understand. What's your question?

Comment: 5) use String.equals to compare strings otherwhise you compare references

Comment: @Stefano enough already. Speaking of 'compreensible', you could try spelling correctly yourself.

Comment: I guess by now you both see what my question was, I will be even clearer next time. My question btw was why the string stored in nextInt not equivalent to the string I declared called dragon.

Comment: @Carloz High No I don't see. What 'string stored in nextInt'? You don't have a variable called `nextInt`; you aren't calling `nextInt()`; I don't know what you mean. Still.

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.equals` when comparing strings. `==` checks if the reference is the same. `String.equals` tests if the objects are the same.

So instead of `if(d==a2)` use `if(d.equals(a2))`

Comment: That solves part of his problem. The next problem he'll have is when he tries to compare a `String` to a `double`

Comment: True, but I left that out since the code he used for that is not listed in the question. He only mentions using `double` and `nextDouble()` which should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try `if (d.equals(a2))`, use equals for String comparison.

Answer (score 1):

First you're trying to compare *reference values*, not the contents of the `String` objects.

As others have noted, you need to use the `String.equals(String otherString)` method.

Next, you're reading `1.45` in as a `String`, not a `double`. These two things are not comparable. You need to read in `1.45` as a `double`;

```
String a1 = x.next();
String a2 = x.next();
String a3 = x.next();
double d1 = x.nextDouble();
```

This would convert your line `A dragon is 1.45` to three `String`s ('A', 'dragon', 'is') and a `double` (1.45)

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Roach, that's answered my question perfectly.